# Generate word permutations from FirstName, LastName and MiddleName

Tags: algorithm, t-sql, permutation

Let us say I have the following name: **`John Smith Alexander`**.
I want to get `John Alexander Smith`; `Smith John Alexander`; `Alexander Smith John`; `etc.`

The middle name doesn't have to exist so from **`John Smith`** I should receive just `John Smith` and `Smith John`.

Also the full name might contain 4 words or more, but very rarely.

Comment: If a full name contains more than three words, do "middle name rules" apply to all but the first and last?

Comment: @LordTorgamus Well, It doesn't actually matter which is the middle. I just need to shuffle all the words.

Comment: If middle names don't have to exist, then it certainly does matter, unless I'm really misunderstanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get word permutations. Period. 2 or more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First break up the string:

```
DECLARE @separator char(1)
DECLARE @NameParts TABLE (PartId INT IDENTITY, part varchar(50))
DECLARE @Name varchar(50)
SET @separator = ' '
SET @name = 'John Smith Alexander'
;WITH Parts(pn, start, finish) AS (
  SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@separator, @Name)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pn + 1, finish + 1, CHARINDEX(@separator, @Name, finish + 1)
  FROM Parts
  WHERE finish > 0
)
INSERT INTO @NameParts(part)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Name, start, CASE WHEN finish > 0 THEN finish-start ELSE 50 END)
FROM Parts
```

Then get the permutations:

```
DECLARE @tokencount int
SELECT @tokencount = COUNT(*) FROM @NameParts

;WITH Subsets AS 
(
SELECT CAST(' ' + part AS VARCHAR(MAX)) Permutation,
CAST(1 AS INT) AS Iteration
FROM @NameParts 
UNION ALL
SELECT Permutation + ' ' + part  AS Permutation, Iteration + 1 AS Iteration
FROM Subsets s 
JOIN @NameParts n ON s.Permutation NOT LIKE '%' + n.part + '%'
)
SELECT STUFF(Permutation,1,1,'') As Perm 
FROM SUBSETS
WHERE Iteration = @tokencount
```

Comment: Thank you! Fast and efficient!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.name, b.name, c.name 
FROM test a, test b, test c 
WHERE a.name != b.name 
  AND a.name != c.name 
  AND b.name != c.name;
```

works for my database, which isn't tsql. Of course it will not work without modification for 2 or 4 names, and get unmaintainable for more than 4 names.

For names like `John Richard John` it will not work too.